# Delete every odd index in array until number of elements in array become 1

Tags: algorithm, logic

You have an Array of size n=10;

arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

Operation 1:- Delete every odd index 
           :- 1,3,5,7,9
        Now arr[]={2,4,6,8,10}

Repeat Operation 1 Unless size of array become one
 in this case Answer is  :-8

Is there any formula threw which i can directly fine out this.

Comment: Looks like its a university assignment

Comment: @NadeemIqbal no it's just a competitive  programming question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Assuming indices are starting from 1.

then,

Mathematical interpretation:

```
 Index of the element that will stay up to the end = 2^(⌊log2 n⌋) 
 where ⌊n⌋ is: floor of log of n base 2.
 And, n is the size of the array.
```

Index of the element at the end will always be the highest 2^k <= n possible, where k is a positive integer.

For example: If n=20 then the index of the element which will make up to the last will be 16.

that is, 2^4

If n=40, the answer will be 32 ==> 2^5

2) If Indices starts from zero, then the 0th element will stay until the end.